# Node, Express API App on Azure giving Container Start Failure error

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I have an existing Node and Express API application which I am trying to deploy to Azure WebApps. Deployment goes fine. But when I try to access the APIs, nothing happens. When I check log, I see following: "Container chdemoapi_0_f2df43ac didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start""Container chdemoapi_0_4e583132 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start"
This is how my index.js file looks:

```
    const config = require('./common/config/env.config.js');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const AuthorizationRouter = require('./auth/routes.config');
const LeadsRouter = require('./leads/routes.config');
const DemoRouter = require('./demo/routes.config');
const MentorRouter = require('./mentors/routes.config');



app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Length');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Range, x-access-token');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return res.send(200);
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
AuthorizationRouter.routesConfig(app);
LeadsRouter.routesConfig(app);
DemoRouter.routesConfig(app);
MentorRouter.routesConfig(app);



app.listen(config.port, function () {
    console.log('app listening at port %s', config.port);
});
```

This is how my env.config file looks:

```
 module.exports = {        "port": 3600,        
//"appEndpoint": "http://localhost:3600",        
//"apiEndpoint": "http://localhost:3600",        
"appEndpoint": "https://chdemoapi.azurewebsites.net:3600",       
 "apiEndpoint": "https://chdemoapi.azurewebsites.net:3600",       
 "jwt_expiration_in_seconds": 36000,        
"environment": "dev",    
};
```

This is how my package.json file looks:

```
{"name": "ch-demo-services",      
"version": "1.0.0",      
"description": "microservices for demo module",      
"main": "index.js",      
"start":"node index.js",      
"scripts": {"test": 
"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"},      
"author": "",      "license": "ISC",      
"dependencies": { "express": "^4.17.1", "generate-password": "^1.5.1",        
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",        "mailgen": "^2.0.13",        "moment": "^2.27.0",        "mongoose": 
"^5.9.18",        "nodemailer": "^6.4.10",        "uuid": "^8.1.0"      }    }
```

In Application settings, I have also added WEBSITES_PORT:3600.
In my localhost, I was accessing API like: http://localhost:3600/listDemoSlotsAfter deploying to Azure, I am trying to access them like: https://chdemoapi.azurewebsites.net:3600/listDemoSlots. But nothing happens and I see above logs.
What's wrong with my settings.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of your error message, it is the port problem.

Azure Web App service [only supports http port 80 and https port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516071/open-additional-ports-on-azure-web-app). It is recommended to replace `https://chdemoapi.azurewebsites.net:3600` with `https://chdemoapi.azurewebsites.net:443`. Then restart the application.