# Django channels and azure

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, django-channels

I am trying to deploy django channels in azure.

I have already integrated it with azure redis cache and it's working good in local host.

I have tried the normal deployment of django apps in azure, everything except sockets are working.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
    'CONFIG': {
        "hosts": [(f'redis://:{os.environ["REDISPASS"]}@mywebsite.redis.cache.windows.net:6379/0')],
    },
},
```

}

It's showing unexpected error website closed unexpectedly.

I have followed this basic stater code for implementing django channels.

[Tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your config file, I saw you use port 6379.

This doesn't work, you can [only use https port 443 and http port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516071/open-additional-ports-on-azure-web-app) in the azure webapp service.

If you must use a custom port such as 6379, it is recommended to use a server and open a secure port, then the webapp will not be deployed on azure.

Comment: Yes actually this is fine but should I make any changes for asgi as django channels will come under asgi not wsgi?

Comment: ASGI is an extension of WSGI, supporting the original mode of WSGI and the expansion of WebSocket.