# Communication between Azure VM and Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-webapps, azure-vm

I'm very newbie on Azure, so I am probably asking a very basic question, please be patient with me.

I have an Azure Red Hat VM and a java Azure App Service Web App, deployed on the same resource group and the same region.
I need the VM to perform RMI calls to the Web App on port 12999.

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516071/open-additional-ports-on-azure-web-app) that the Azure Web App just exposes ports 80 and 443.

I've also read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features) that the inbound communication to Azure App Service is possible through Service Endpoints, but it is not clear to me how I should configure the VNet.

Is there any way to have the RMI communication on port 12999 from VM to Web App?

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: FYI Resource Groups have no impact on connectivity; they're just an organizational & security boundary (security for making changes to Azure services, deleting them, etc).

Comment: Ok, clear, thanks a lot David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to have the RMI communication on port 12999 from VM to Web App?

No. As you already found, Web Apps only expose ports 80 and 443. Service Endpoints etc. do not change that.