# Question on Spring Boot + Azure Listening Port

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

I am a spring boot starter and a cloud starter, and I deploy my spring boot project (Rest API) in Azure via App Service (Using Intellij Plugin Azure ToolKit).

When I get my deploy url which is like https://DOMAIN.azurewebsites.net, I am curious why I can fetch my data without typing :8080 PORT. I don't add the server.port=8080 in my application.properties.

Usually, if you are deploying your spring boot project in a Linux instance (Both AWS EC2 and Azure VM), and you can get your data by typing:  http://<YOUR_LINUX_PUBLIC_IP>:8000

I try to get my data by both https://DOMAIN.azurewebsites.net and http://.azurewebsites.net, and they all work.

However, if I try: https://****.azurewebsites.net:**8000**, it shows I can not access this URL. Is Azure applying my Spring Boot Service to both HTTPS and HTTP port by default?

Comment: By default, the embedded server starts on port 8080.

Comment: Hi, That's the typo. I should change it to 8080, but still not working

Comment: Hi @Honghai Mei, Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @Joseph, I am so sorry to reply to you so late, thanks for ur answering! Looks like Web App Serivce in Azure only open 443 and 80 Ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Apps don't have a port-mapping feature. The only ports open for Web Apps are 80 and 443.
`https://DOMAIN.azurewebsites.net:443`
`http://DOMAIN.azurewebsites.net:80`
Traffic Manager does not provide port-mapping. You'd need to run your own proxy for handling this.
[image]

So we can't specify 8080 port in Web Apps. If you need that control, you can use Cloud Services or Virtual Machines.
Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43519003/13979487).